# Question About Computer History in Germany

Tags: computers

I asked this question on the German Stack Exchange, but was told that the EE site might provide better feedback. So, I have a question about a statement on a device produced in West Germany in 1965. I have the original German translation below, along with my own translation.

**What is meant by "simulation" here? How could a simulation of a Siemens machine be achieved? Was it a remote simulation? Time-sharing wasn't used very often then.**

> *Gruppenschulungsgerät für verzweigende Programme bestehend aus einer zentralen Steuereinheit (bzw. deren Simulation durch den Prozeßrechner
>   Siemens 303 P)*
>
> Group-training device for branching programs consisting of its central
>   control unit or its simulation by a Siemens 303
>   [image: Geromat III]

Comment: Do you have a longer section of the text?  Ich kann Deutsch sehr gut verstehen, aber die Auszug is zu kurz - es fehlt einiges an Kontext.

Comment: It's also not clear that "bzw" should be translated as "or". In context, are they talking about two different use cases (or operations or ...) and in one case they use the central control unit and in another case they use a simulation? Then the sense of "bzw" might be more clear.

Comment: As @JRE says, we need a lot more context. Where did you find this description?

Comment: Small correction to your German text: "Gruppenschulungsgerät für verzweigende Programme bestehend aus einer zentralen Steuereinheit (bzw. deren Simulation durch den Prozeßrechner Siemens 303 P)"  Slight mixup splitting words and capitalization in the transcription.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I just added a picture. @jre & others

Answer (score 1):

A *Prozessrechner* in the sense of that old machine is a Minicomputer (small mainframe). The Siemens 300 systems had been somewhat popular in the 1970ies.

So that projected *Geromat III* could either use its own CPU or it could have a dumb terminal installed along with the multimedia equipment and communicate with a program on the Siemens 303.

Answer (score 0):

"Its (simulation)" refers to "central processing unit".

The device

- either consist of the central processing unit
- or it consists of a simulation of the central processing unit and in that case the simulation is done by a Siemens 303 P computer.

What's unclear?

Comment: Hi, @curd. I suppose to be more specific, I was wondering how a device as a whole could be simulated. Simulation of the program makes sense to me. But the device in question not so much. Thanks, still a helpful answer.

Comment: @Parever: that's why I emphasized that the sentence didn't say that the whole device is simulated but only the CPU.